# Grunt cant find tasks

Tags: ubuntu, gruntjs

After several tries i did not come up with this is error.
Grunt do not find any task i installed from npm. Here is my very basic package.json:

```
{
    "name" : "MyProject",
    "version" : "0.0.1",
    "dependencies" : {
        "grunt" : "~0.4.5",
        "grunt-contrib-watch" : "~0.6.1",
        "grunt-contrib-compass" : "~1.0.1",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify" : "~0.6.0",
        "matchdep" : "~0.3.0"
    }
}
```

After i run  `npm install`  i got the node_modules folder inside the root folder.

I create a basic gruntfile.js for testing purposes that looks like this:

```
module.exports function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
        grunt.initConfig({
            uglify :{
                my_target : {
                    files : {
                        '/js/script.js' : ['/components/js/script.js']
                    } //files
                } //my_target
            } //uglify
        }) //initConfig
} // exports
```

Now after i moved from the terminal into my folder i run this command `grunt uglify`.

This is the output:

```
/var/www/html/lp/gruntfile.js:1
 (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { module.exports function(g
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^
Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
Warning: Task "uglify" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Any idea about what am i doing wrong ? I am actually on an ubuntu based system.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `=` after `module.exports`. Here's a cleaned up version of your Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        meta: {
            version: '0.1.0'
        },
        uglify: {
            my_target: {
                files: {
                    '/js/script.js': ['/components/js/script.js']
                } //files
            } //my_target
        } //uglify
    }); //initConfig
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
}; // exports
```

Comment: @TheBluerock Happy to help. If this completes your question please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark outline on the left. If only so others know this question is done.

Answer (score 0):

Try registerting the task:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
```

Or potentially:

```
grunt.registerTask('uglify', ['uglify']);
```